# How do you create a mailing list with Lotus Notes?

Tags: email, database, lotus-notes, mailing-lists

I have a list of users of an application stored in an SQL database.  I'd like to be able to email these people with useful information.

Two parts to the question.

1. How do I send queries to an SQL database from Lotus Notes (v6.5.5), in order to retrieve the email addresses?  (I'm okay with what the contents of the query should be, I just need to know how to get Notes talking to the database.)
2. How do I programmatically store these addresses as a group contact?

Answer (score 1):

You can mail merge to Notes using Excel [1](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?name=MailMerge%20Excel%20to%20Notes) and presumably you can get the data to Excel using ODBC.